# Include static HTML folder/files in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I'm using create-react-app with the react-router-dom module for my React app. I have a subfolder containing static HTML/CSS/JS that I'd like the react app to render. It could be as simple as having the router show /static/index.html.

I've searched around and there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as to how to so this using create-react-app. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not following the question. Are you trying to have a route, meaning when the user goes to www.myWebsite.com/myRoute, it should display a component for myRoute

Comment: @SteveCahn yes exactly

Answer (score -2):

In order to use routing in your react app, you have to do the following:

### Setup

1. Install react by opening the terminal/cmd, going to the current apps directory, and type in the following command: `npm i react-router-dom`. Hit enter and let it install.
2. Next, go to the `index.js` file, and import `BrowserRouter`, by adding the following line at the beginning of your code: `import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`
3. Then change your render thing to look like this:

   ReactDOM.render(
       
           
       ,
       document.getElementById('root')
   );

What that does, is it basically tells react that `App` will have routing support.

5. Now go to your `app.jsx` file and import the following: `import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`. (I'll explain what they all are later on.)

Now that the behind-the-scenes is setup, we can start adding routes, or paths, to out app.

### Apply Routes

1. Go to your `app.jsx` file and at the `render` part instead of just
   having components there, let's make a route. (A route just means a
   url path.)
2. You can have `components` that are always there, no matter what the url path is. In order to do that, just don't have those items as routes. See the example below for more clarification.
3. To create a route just add the following code: `<Route path="/myPath" component={myComponent} />`
4. `myComponent` will display when the user goes to `www.myWebsite.com/myPath`.

The problem with this, is say you have a route to `/myPath`, and a route to `/` (the home page, i.e. `www.myWebsite.com/`), then when the user navigates to `www.myWebsite.com/myPath`, the home page will also display. To prevent that from happening, just wrapp all the routes in a `<Switch></Switch>` component.

So the final code in the render part of `app.jsx` will look is like this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="bg" />
        // Will always show `Header` no matter what the rout is.
        <Header/>

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/about" component={about} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={WelcomContent} />
        </Switch>

        // Will always show `Footer` no matter what the rout is.
        <Footer />
    </div>
);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Yes but I want to use static HTML files for this...not sure how to do this still...

Comment: For that you will have to use node.js I believe. Why do u want to specifically want to load the whole html page